# Need help understanding sentence with term "over constraining"

Tags: meaning

> We do not believe in over constraining the team beyond its capacity.

I'm having trouble understanding that sentence.

What does "over constraining" mean?  I found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/a-word-for-the-meaning-of-over-constrained) but I don't see how those answers help in this example.

I think (hope!) the intent of the original was along the lines of: "We do not believe in pushing the team beyond its capacity."

... but is that restatement truly equivalent to the original example?

many thanks, first time post to ELU!

Comment: Read literally (and somewhat tongue in cheek), it means, "We do not believe in putting so many restrictions on the team that they lose their minds."

Comment: @Gnawme - I find myself feeling oddly reassured by this explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Hypo.  You are *totally* confused here. Gnawme was **just being sarcastic**.  It is **just a typo**, it is meaningless.  It is meant to read "overburdening..."

Comment: Gnawme dude:  (1) this site is not funny.  (2) jokes are not funny.  (3) you are incredibly not funny.  (4) your specific "joke" there is incredibly not funny. (5) this is the single most confused site on the entire SO network, and whenever anyone tries to add a "joke" it is spectacularly not funny and merely adds to confusion - and wastes time such as my time is wasting now. And that's not funny.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is either a typo or a case of incorrect usage. Perhaps the person who wrote this wanted to say

"We do not believe in **overstraining** the team beyond its capacity."

Comment: ... which, of course, would still be horrible. "Over" already means "beyond capacity".

Comment: I agree with you. If the person really meant to write overstraining (or any "over-" ) here, it is redundant because of the "beyond capacity".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is almost certainly just a typo. It makes very little sense.

It's worth noting that in English, there is a real trend to try to write and talk in a "overly complicated" manner. This results in idiocy.

The writer, in their confused mind, probably just meant:

"We do not believe in overloading the team beyond its capacity."

That's a common sort of phrase.

It could be that the writer was being extremely subtle (perhaps sharing an inside joke) and literally meant what it says, but it's 99.9% chance it's simply a typo.

Comment: But isn't that still a bit redundant? Trying to rephrase your suggestion in the positive gives me: "We do believe in overloading the team _within_ its capacity"  or  "We do believe in loading the team beyond its capacity."

Comment: I don't know how clear I can be dude.  It is a typographical error.  That's all there is to it champ!  The person meant to type "overloading the team beyond its capacity" - it's just that simple.

Comment: It's extremely common in English that very, very stupid people - people who can barely think - have heard a "complicated sounding" "sophisticated" phrase, and they rehash it in a completely incorrect manner, mixing-up words meaninglessly. There is a whole field of study about this. That's all you're seeing here, it's just that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the writer of the original sentence meant to say that "We" are opposed to burdening "the team" with an intolerable number of constraints. This wording would have worked:

> Our policy is to avoid imposing unreasonable constraints on the team.

It is possible, of course, that the original author didn't intend to use the word *constraining* at all—but I don't see any reason to assume that he or she did not. In many real-world instances, onerous internal reporting requirements, unrealistic turn-around times, and needlessly narrow limitations on subject matter can function as harmful constraints on a team's creativity and productivity; and I can imagine that something of this sort was on the author's mind.

But *constraining* (with its sense of preventing a person or team from moving freely) makes a poor match with "beyond its capacity" (which suggests being pushed outside the bounds of what is reasonable). That combination, reinforced by the completely unnecessary introduction of the word *over*, yields an overwritten, tone-deaf sentence.